# Register Android app for voice broadcast intents

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I realize this question has been asked in the past but the latest one I can find is from 2011 so I thought it was applicable to bring this up again.  Let me explain my requirement in question through an example.

Our company makes relay control boards which you can operate from android.  You can take a look at them [here](http://www.controlanything.com/Relay/Relay/ANDROID_RELAY-STANDARD).
We have Bluetooth, WiFi, and Ethernet relay boards which you can operate from android using our free app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.controlanything.NCDTCPRelay&hl=en).
Sorry if this is starting to sound like a sales pitch just trying to put things into context.  These relays could be used for something such as opening a garage door.

My friend recently got an Android watch which supports the OK Google voice commands.  We thought it would be cool to run a background service started from the application which could register a receiver for voice activated broadcast intents.  So if the speech command matched a string such as "OK Google Open garage door", which the user could edit in the app, we could connect to the relay board and and turn it on momentarily which would result in opening the garage door.

So is this possible?  If not why the heck not?  Sounds like something we as Android developers should have access to and could open up a whole world of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Google Now fires intents in response to voice commands, see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Now

This is not quite what you're asking but it's new since 2011, so it's worth mentioning.

Starting with API level 21 there is also an AlwaysOnHotwordDetector API (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/voice/package-summary.html), which might allow you to implement your own customized hotword detector if Google Now does not provide the required functionality. (I haven't experimented with it myself yet.)